# Does NASA no longer own a "Vomit Comet?"

Tags: nasa, microgravity, training

[This Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduced-gravity_aircraft#NASA) seems to suggest that NASA no longer owns an aircraft capable of simulating weightlessness, and that such astronaut training is now contracted from a private company.  Can this be confirmed by an independent source?

Related: [How do reduced gravity aircraft work?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/23301/26446)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The last NASA reduced gravity aircraft I can [find](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_NASA_aircraft) is a C-9, registration N932NA, which is listed as [stored](https://www.planelogger.com/Aircraft/Search?registration=N932NA) (i.e. mothballed at Davis Monthan).

This agrees with the note on the [Reduced gravity program](https://reducedgravity.jsc.nasa.gov/) page:

> Website updated September 29, 2014
>
> NASA has not decided how or if Microgravity Flights will occur in the future. This website will be updated as new guidance is released.